# Covariant derivative vanishes: magnitude does not change?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields

I read that if the coviariant derivative of a vector $V^\mu$ along a curve $x^\mu(\sigma)$ in GR vanishes:

$$\frac{D V^\mu}{D\sigma}=0 ~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$

then also the magnitude of this vector vanishes:

$$\frac{d}{d\sigma}\left(V^\mu V_\mu\right)=0 ~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$

When I try to show this I start with the LHS of (2):

$$\frac{d}{d\sigma}\left(V^\mu V_\mu\right)=2\frac{dV^\mu}{d\sigma}V_\mu$$

now I use (1), i.e. $\frac{D V^\mu}{D\sigma}=0=\frac{dV^\mu}{d\sigma}+\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\sigma}V^\beta$:

$$\frac{d}{d\sigma}\left(V^\mu V_\mu\right)=2\frac{dV^\mu}{d\sigma}V_\mu=-2V_\mu \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^\alpha}{d\sigma}V^\beta$$.

But I cannot see that this is zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will omit $d\sigma$ for simplicity.

Actually $d(V^\mu V_\mu) = V_\mu dV^\mu + V^\mu dV_\mu \neq 2V_\mu dV^\mu$     (1)

here you should substitute covariant derivatives for upper and lower indices accordingly:

$DV_\mu = dV_\mu - \Gamma^\beta_{\mu\alpha}dx^\alpha V_\beta = 0 $ (2)

$DV^\mu = dV^\mu + \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}dx^\alpha V^\beta = 0 $ (3)

Obtain $dV_\mu$ and $dV^\mu$, substitute them to (1) and voilà.